# Update ListView dynamically when Log file updated

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.7

I have a log file in .txt format, that is being updated continuously. Then I want to show the file content in ListView (PyQt5) dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use a `QFileSystemWatcher` to detect when you file has been modified.

A quick example:

```
class LogWatcher(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.watcher = QFileSystemWatcher()
        self.watcher.addPath("./foobar.txt") # The file you want to check
        self.watcher.fileChanged.connect(self.displayLine)

    def displayLine(self, path): # Will be called when the file has changed
        print(path, "has changed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    logger = LogWatcher()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Each time the file foobar.txt changes, the method `displayLine` is called